# relation between process management in Linux and process scheduling in operating system

Tags: command-line, linux-headers

I wanna know if there is a relation between the process management in Linux when using (ps & nice - renice) commands. And the process scheduling and queuing related to the operating systems perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ps` command lists processes and shows their scheduling parameters and other process attributes.

The `renice` and `nice` commands change and set the "nice" of one or more processes.  (Nice is one of the scheduling parameters that affects priority.)

Almost everything about a process affects its scheduling.